# Code first One to many to many relationship all different table

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes:

1. "Client" with multiple properties and `public virtual ICollection<LifeStyle>;`
2. "Lifestyle" with multiple properties and `public virtual ICollection<Hobbies>;`
3. "Hobbies" with `id` and `name`;

I use the class "Hobbies" to populate a multiple select in view side and in server side, I'd like to save:
The selected client has multiple lifestyles and lifestyles has the options that I choose in view.

I have a table by each class but I need to create an additional table with a relation between Client, Lifestyle, and hobbies. 
For example

```
ClientId LifestyleId HobbieId   
1 1 1   
1 1 2 
1 1 3 
1 2 1 
1 2 3
```

Comment: Post your attempt.

Comment: I post a answer because in this method I can't create a break

Answer (score 0):

Classic Normalizaton question ... [Rettig Normalization Poster](http://www.informationqualitysolutions.com/FreeStuff/rettigNormalizationPoster.pdf)

Check out the Puppies/Tricks/Costumes example (4th Normal).  You are basically looking to create a "join" table that contains 1 of each key (Client/Lifestyle/Hobbies).  This compound key must be Unique (but is not your  primary key ... use a surrogate).

Your Client class would have a virtual ICollection of the join table.  Ditto for Lifestyles & Hobbies.

Your Join class would have a virtual to its parents for navigation.  Be aware of and handle the potential for circular references.

You haven't specified how you are going to retrieve your data?  SqlCommand?  Stored Proc?  Entity Framework (ORM)?  (assuming SQL Server)

PS: Badly formed question btw.  Need to be more complete.  Give a generic question, all you get is generic answer.